# How to manage session across multiple APIs

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, microservices

I have a very basic question as I was watching few tutorials related to Microservices. If I am creating multiple microservices for 1 application, should I need to implement Authentication and Authorization for all microservices? For example If I have an e-commerce website and I have multiple microservices with certain endpoints for the purchase model.

1. As a user when I login to the UI, initially calling in AccountManagement microservice ( which has few functionality such Register/Login/Reset/Revoke) and then move from one feature to another which interim calls another microservice (should the next microservice read the cookie information and authenticate automatically ? Is that how it works?
2. Will my other microservices also have all features of the Account management microservice or only authenticating through Refresh token?

I am fairly new to this concept in microservices and trying to grasp as much as I can through tutorials but these questions are something I still struggle to understand properly.

Comment: I would suggest look on how OAuth or single sig on Works. It will answer your question.

Comment: If your microservice is a URL that anyone can access, then yes it should always be secured. In C#, once you've set up the authorisation, you just need to decorate your methods with `[Authorize]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/authorization-net-microservices-web-applications You don't have to worry about cookies etc.

Comment: Decouple your authentication service out, your authentication service will generate a access and refresh token based on some hashing algorithm like `HS256` store the secret to make the hash. Now in `ConfigureServices()` method of each microservice use the [`.AddJwtBearer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-5.0) extension method to validate the access token using `TokenValidationParameters` and decorate each method in your microservice with the `Authorize` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1.
Token Based Authentication
It is always ok for you to build stateful application for monolith but not for stateless microservices. Session-based authentication works well for Monolith. However, for microservices since you need to route requests to multiple independent services. To maintain statelessness in our system, we opted to use token authentication. We packaged user claims in the jwt. Hence, we need Authentication for Microservice.
You can apply SSO based approach.

When a user logs in for the first time from any frontend app, a cookie called jwt-token gets created on the api-gateway. The cookie’s domain is .myorg.com and hence accessible to all myorg.com subdomain. When a request is made from any of the frontend apps to the api gateway, we extract the cookie named jwt-token if set. If not set, we assume the user is not logged in and return a 401-status code from the api-gateway.
If your microservices are not exposed to internet, you can also introduce basic authentication. This will also make sure reducing any security risks internal to your company.

Answer 2.
Microservice follow DDD (Domain Drive Design) Principle which makes them independent small application. You should not add any functionality of Account management (it is an independent Service). Other Service should have their authentication along with their domain which can be like Customer, Payment, Audit etc.

Refer These articles :

1. https://medium.com/technology-learning/how-we-solved-authentication-and-authorization-in-our-microservice-architecture-994539d1b6e6
2. https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/building-domain-driven-microservices-af688aa1b1b8

Comment: Thank you, this is much clear explanation and the articles you shared cleared all my doubts that I had.